# Error:android.view.View$OnClickListener on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, arraylist, listadapter

I'm getting a NullPointerException when I try to set a `clickListener` to ImageView.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

activity_list_funny.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:padding="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="4dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_purple"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="1dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgbtn_favorite1"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/name1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_black_24dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/add_favr" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And Here When I Initiate ImageView By making An Object In My MainActivity And providing It An OnClickListener
And When I RuN It It force closes And Shows null object references

MainActivity.java

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> quotes;
ArrayAdapter adapter;
TextView t1,t2;
ListView list;
ImageView i;      
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_funny_quotes);
    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
    isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
    c = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout1);

    **i=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_favorite1);**

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.activity_list_funny);
    i.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
```

}

Comment: Share your activity code (where you deal with imgbtn_favorite1 ImageView)

Comment: Please attach the **relevant** Java code. And Stop WritinG LikE ThiS Please.

Comment: @GuilhermeP Updated.

Comment: Something you are doing is causing the view to not load on the activity `onStart()`:
`at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)`. My guess is it is not specifically with the `i` ImageView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is:

You activity is using following layout: `R.layout.activity_funny_quotes`

But your button is inside: `R.layout.activity_list_funny`

This way, `findViewById` returns `null` and `i == null`

**When will not be null**

`i=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_favorite1);` will return a valid `ImageView` only after you set the adapter to your ListView (`list.setAdapter(adapter)`). This way, the `ImageView` will be added to the screen and `findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_favorite1)` may return a valid `ImageView`

Even then, your list must not be empty. If the list is empty, no `ImageView` will be returned to the screen and you will keep receiveing `null`

There's another problem: if your list has several items, `findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_favorite1)` will return only the `ImageView` of the first item.

**How to Fix**

It's hard to tell you how to proper fix your issue.

You are trying to add a `clickListener` to an `ImageView` that will be displayed in your `ListView`.

Maybe, it is better to define a `ListView.setOnItemClickListener()` instead to add a `clickListener` to your `ImageView`

Comment: Hey Thanks Now Its Being Loaded But When I Click On The Src Nothing happens

Comment: Watch my Comment Down @GuilhermeP

Answer (score 1):

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                FunnyQuotes.this, quotes, R.layout.activity_list_funny,
                new String[]{TAG_ID,TAG_NAME,},
                new int[]{R.id.id1, R.id.name1}


        );

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        i.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                i.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

See This @GuilhermeP

Answer (score 0):

Check `i` before invoking a method

```
if (i != null) {
    i.setOnClickListener(...);
}
else {
    Log.d(TAG, "Couldn't find ImageView");
}
```

Comment: Image Is Being Loaded 
Only When I Set OnClickListener iN My MainActivity 
It Force Stop Else Its Fine